# Topographical correction of Sentinel-2 data

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, remote-sensing

I tried to apply the SCS+C, a modified Sun-canopy-sensor topographic correction, algorithm for all scenes over my study area for a year.
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1499030
But it ended with errors.

```
var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[-115.51858045584667, 45.29650713146457],
          [-115.51858045584667, 44.2632748294202],
          [-113.60146619803417, 44.2632748294202],
          [-113.60146619803417, 45.29650713146457]]], null, false);

//Apply topographic correction on all S2 scenes of year 2019 over my ROI

function cloud_mask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  var out = image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image);
  return out;
  }

var dem = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

function topoCorr_IC(img){

  // Extract image metadata about solar position
  var SZ_rad = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE'))).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000)); 
  var SA_rad = ee.Image.constant(ee.Number(img.get('MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE')).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180)).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000)); 
  // Creat terrain layers
  var slp = ee.Terrain.slope(dem).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));
  var slp_rad = ee.Terrain.slope(dem).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));
  var asp_rad = ee.Terrain.aspect(dem).multiply(3.14159265359).divide(180).clip(img.geometry().buffer(10000));

  // Calculate the Illumination Condition (IC)
  // slope part of the illumination condition
  var cosZ = SZ_rad.cos();
  var cosS = slp_rad.cos();
  var slope_illumination = cosS.expression("cosZ * cosS", 
                                          {'cosZ': cosZ,
                                           'cosS': cosS.select('slope')});
  // aspect part of the illumination condition
  var sinZ = SZ_rad.sin(); 
  var sinS = slp_rad.sin();
  var cosAziDiff = (SA_rad.subtract(asp_rad)).cos();
  var aspect_illumination = sinZ.expression("sinZ * sinS * cosAziDiff", 
                                           {'sinZ': sinZ,
                                            'sinS': sinS,
                                            'cosAziDiff': cosAziDiff});
  // full illumination condition (IC)
  var ic = slope_illumination.add(aspect_illumination);

  // Add IC to original image
  var img_plus_ic = ee.Image(img.addBands(ic.rename('IC')).addBands(cosZ.rename('cosZ')).addBands(cosS.rename('cosS')).addBands(slp.rename('slope')));
  return img_plus_ic;
}

function topoCorr_SCSc(img){
    var img_plus_ic = img;
    var mask1 = img_plus_ic.select('B8').gt(-0.1);
    var mask2 = img_plus_ic.select('slope').gte(5) //apply to terrain has slop greater than 5 degree
                            .and(img_plus_ic.select('IC').gte(0));
    var img_plus_ic_mask2 = ee.Image(img_plus_ic.updateMask(mask2));

    var bandList = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12']; // Specify Bands to topographically correct

    function apply_SCSccorr(bandList){
      var method = 'SCSc';
      var out = img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC', bandList).reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), // Compute coefficients: a(slope), b(offset), c(b/a)
      geometry: ee.Geometry(img.geometry().buffer(-5000)), // trim off the outer edges of the image for linear relationship 
      scale: 100,
      maxPixels: 10e13
      }); 
      var out_a = ee.Number(out.get('scale'));
      var out_b = ee.Number(out.get('offset'));
      var out_c = ee.Number(out.get('offset')).divide(ee.Number(out.get('scale')));

      //apply the SCSc correction
      var SCSc_output = img_plus_ic_mask2.expression("((image * (cosB * cosZ + cvalue)) / (ic + cvalue))", {
        'image': img_plus_ic_mask2.select(bandList),
        'ic': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC'),
        'cosB': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('cosS'),
        'cosZ': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('cosZ'),
        'cvalue': out_c
      });

      return ee.Image(SCSc_output);
    }

    var img_SCSccorr = ee.Image(bandList.map(apply_SCSccorr)).addBands(img_plus_ic.select('IC'));
    var bandList_IC = ee.List([bandList, 'IC']).flatten();
    return img_SCSccorr.unmask(img_plus_ic.select(bandList_IC))
                       .addBands(mask1.rename('initMask'))
                       .addBands(mask2.rename('corrMask'));
  }

var S2_original = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                    .filterBounds(roi)
                    .filterDate('2019-01-01','2019-12-31')
                    .filterMetadata('MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE', 'less_than', 85)
                    .map(cloud_mask);

var S2_topo_corr = S2_original
                    .map(topoCorr_IC) 
                    .map(topoCorr_SCSc);

Map.addLayer(
              S2_original.select(['B4','B3','B2'])
              .reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25])).clip(roi),
              {min:0,max:0.2},
              'Original', true
);

Map.addLayer(
              S2_topo_corr.select(['B4','B3','B2'])
              .reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25])).clip(roi),
              {min:0,max:0.2},
              'Corrected', true
)
```

Error:

```
Corrected: Tile error: Too many concurrent aggregations.
```

However, there should be possible ways to solve it in the GEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all the `reduceRegion()` calls are simply too much for EE to handle in one go. If you increase the scale, it works better. What scale you need in order to get good results is a different question.

There's a second problem with your code. Some images are more or less completely masked out. That causes `out_a` and `out_b` to be `null`, giving error when calculating `out_c`. You can protect against that with an `ee.Algorithms.If()`.

```
function apply_SCSccorr(bandList){
  var method = 'SCSc';
  var out = img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC', bandList).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), // Compute coefficients: a(slope), b(offset), c(b/a)
  geometry: ee.Geometry(img.geometry().buffer(-5000)), // trim off the outer edges of the image for linear relationship 
  scale: 500,
  maxPixels: 10e13
  }); 
  var out_a = ee.Number(out.get('scale'));
  var out_b = ee.Number(out.get('offset'));
  // out_a and out_b can be null giving error when calculating out_c
  // var out_c = ee.Number(out.get('offset')).divide(ee.Number(out.get('scale')));      
  var out_c = ee.Algorithms.If(
    out_a, 
    ee.Image(ee.Number(out.get('offset')).divide(ee.Number(out.get('scale')))),
    ee.Image() // Masked image
  )

  //apply the SCSc correction
  var SCSc_output = img_plus_ic_mask2.expression("((image * (cosB * cosZ + cvalue)) / (ic + cvalue))", {
    'image': img_plus_ic_mask2.select(bandList),
    'ic': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC'),
    'cosB': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('cosS'),
    'cosZ': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('cosZ'),
    'cvalue': out_c
  });

  return ee.Image(SCSc_output);
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/5b9a63b803612e200975607e19d04597